# Why is my code giving dfferent results everytime?

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network

after a few days where my code was reproducible everytime - it is now not! i don't know what happend, i just changed some lines of codes and i don't know how to fix it!

```
# Code reproduzierbar machen
import numpy as np
import os
import random as rn
import tensorflow as tf
import keras
from keras import backend as K

#-----------------------------Keras reproducible------------------#
SEED = 1234

tf.set_random_seed(SEED)
os.environ['PYTHONHASHSEED'] = str(SEED)
np.random.seed(SEED)
rn.seed(SEED)

session_conf = tf.ConfigProto(
    intra_op_parallelism_threads=1, 
    inter_op_parallelism_threads=1
)
sess = tf.Session(
    graph=tf.get_default_graph(), 
    config=session_conf
)
K.set_session(sess)

# Importiere Datasets (Training und Test)
import pandas as pd
poker_train = pd.read_csv("C:/Users/elihe/Documents/Studium Master/WS 19 und 20/Softwareprojekt/poker-hand-training-true.data")
poker_test = pd.read_csv("C:/Users/elihe/Documents/Studium Master/WS 19 und 20/Softwareprojekt/poker-hand-testing.data")

X_tr = poker_train.iloc[:, 0:10]
y_train = poker_train.iloc[:, 10:11]
X_te = poker_test.iloc[:, 0:10]
y_test = poker_test.iloc[:, 10:11]

from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
sc = StandardScaler()
X_train = sc.fit_transform(X_tr)
X_test = sc.transform(X_te)

# NN mit Keras erstellen
import keras
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense

nen = Sequential()
nen.add(Dense(100, input_dim = 10, activation = 'relu'))
nen.add(Dense(50, activation = 'relu'))
nen.add(Dense(10, activation = 'softmax'))

# Kompilieren
from keras import metrics
nen.compile(loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
nen_fit = nen.fit(X_train, y_train,epochs=2, batch_size=50, verbose=1, validation_split = 0.2, shuffle = False)
```

I took just 2 epochs so that i can see immediately if my Output is the same, normally there would be 500 epochs. The first lines of code made it until today reproducible, but now it is not! I changed the part with the X_te and X_tr, because first i made a OneHotEncoding with the classes y_train and y_test, but now i am not doing it. Also i changed the activation functions from sigmoid to relu and the optimizer from RMSprop to adam. I don't know what to do:(

Comment: just a simple question... every time you rerun to verify if the results are the same, do you restart your kernel?

Comment: yes i do! i also tried just closing everything, shut-down my jupyter notebook, close anaconda and so on - like every possibility. I just found out 1 min ago that if i use the optimizer sgd, then it is reproducible, but with adam it is not....

Comment: Checking your result only after 2 epochs might not be a good idea. Optimization is a stochastic process and although it mostly will converge to same result after enough iterations, after 2 epochs it's only natural to get different results. I would repeat the experiment with more epochs.

Comment: i did it with up to 500 (!) epochs and still got different values